# How to send sms from flutter app when Notification Action is tapped?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter local notifications and upon notification action tap I want to send sms using url launcher. But I am getting exception

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NO_ACTIVITY, Launching a URL requires a foreground activity., null, null)
```

Is there any way to send sms when app in background ?

SMS sending code

```
case 'id_2':
      // Handle 'Alert Client Running Behind' action
      print('Alert Client Running Behind action tapped');
      JobModel jobModel = JobModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(payload));

      String? phoneNumber;
      if (jobModel.is_businessjob == '1') {
        phoneNumber = jobModel.business_phone;
      } else {
        phoneNumber = jobModel.mobile_no;
      }

      if (phoneNumber != null) {
        final Uri smsLaunchUri = Uri(
          scheme: 'sms',
          path: phoneNumber,
          queryParameters: <String, String>{
            'body': Uri.encodeComponent('Hi ${jobModel.client_name ?? ""} im on my way to the job im just running behind, sorry for the delay, ${jobModel.staff_names} '),
          },
        );

        await launchUrl(smsLaunchUri);
      } else {
        showToast('Phone number is not available');
      }

      onClickNotification.add(payload);
      break;
```

The error I'm getting

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NO_ACTIVITY, Launching a URL requires a foreground activity., null, null)
E/flutter ( 6444): #0      UrlLauncherApi.launchUrl (package:url_launcher_android/src/messages.g.dart:123:7)
E/flutter ( 6444): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6444): #1      UrlLauncherAndroid.launchUrl (package:url_launcher_android/url_launcher_android.dart:111:11)
E/flutter ( 6444): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6444): #2      LocalNotifications.onNotificationTap (package:affordable_pest_control/local_notifications.dart:75:13)
E/flutter ( 6444): <asynchronous suspension>
```